# How to count uppercase and lowercase on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, text, feature-extraction

Here's my data

```
No  Body                 
1   DaTa Analytics 2
2   StackOver 67
```

Here's my expected output

```
No  Body                 Uppercase   Lowercase
1   DaTa Analytics 2     3           10
2   StackOver 67         2           7
```

Comment: Give me some time, I'm looking for a much faster non-regex solution.

Comment: I still not choosing the best answer yet

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your patience. Some users don't want to wait before ticking.

Comment: @NabihBawazir - I add new solution with `count`, can you check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract upper and lower case and [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for lengths:

```
df['Uppercase'] = df['Body'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()
df['Lowercase'] = df['Body'].str.findall(r'[a-z]').str.len()
```

Another solution:

```
df['Uppercase'] = df['Body'].str.count(r'[A-Z]')
df['Lowercase'] = df['Body'].str.count(r'[a-z]')

print (df)
   No            Body  Uppercase  Lowercase
0   1  DaTa Analytics          3         10
1   2       StackOver          2          7
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extremely performant solution that manipulates ASCII codes:

```
v = df.Body.values.astype(str)
v = v.view(np.uint8).reshape(len(df), -1)

df['Uppercase'] = ((v >= 65) & (v <= 90)).sum(1)
df['Lowercase'] = ((v >= 97) & (v <= 122)).sum(1)
```

```
df

   No            Body  Uppercase  Lowercase
0   1  DaTa Analytics          3         10
1   2       StackOver          2          7
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# @jezrael1

%%timeit
df['Uppercase'] = df['Body'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()
df['Lowercase'] = df['Body'].str.findall(r'[a-z]').str.len()

979 ms ± 24.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# @jezrael2

%%timeit
df['Uppercase'] = [sum(1 for c in x if c.isupper()) for x in df['Body']]
df['Lowercase'] = [sum(1 for c in x if c.islower()) for x in df['Body']]

1.11 s ± 130 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# in this post

%%timeit
v = df.Body.values.astype(str)
v = v.view(np.uint8).reshape(len(df), -1)

df['Uppercase'] = ((v >= 65) & (v <= 90)).sum(1)
df['Lowercase'] = ((v >= 97) & (v <= 122)).sum(1)

91.8 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Is this type of solutions can be used for emoticon as well, I have performance issues in emoticon

Comment: @NabihBawazir No problem, use `v.view(np.uint16)` instead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I add another solution, can you add to timings? thanks.

Comment: @jezrael No worries, added

Comment: @NabihBawazir If that still doesn't work, try `np.uint32`, it should handle any unicode character in the book.

Comment: I am using AWS m4.large for jupyter notebook and `v = df.Body.values.astype(str)` and give memory error result, with 800 thousands sms, and @jezrael solution work in acceptable performance

Comment: That's sad news, but I guess it cannot be helped.